# Postgresql pgstartup.log file issues

Tags: postgresql, logging

All,

I am running in a development environment and have a dozens of concurrent inserts going in to a table that has a primary key prohibits duplicate records to be inserted. This is exactly what its intended to do. My problem is that I was getting HUGE log files because each duplicate record was being reported to the log file as an ERROR or WARNING. Either way, it was being logged. I turned that off in the config file and now everything is being logged to pgstartup.log. This file gets to be over 20 gigs sometimes. How can I prevent this file fron growing so large too?

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres doesn't feature MERGE, INSERT IGNORE, nor UPSERT :(

Instead of a direct insert, though, you can use a surrogate MERGE or INSERT IGNORE (using CTE) to prevent duplicate inserts:

```
WITH upsert AS
(UPDATE "your table" yt SET .... WHERE yt.key=<KEY VALUE>
  RETURNING yt.*
)
INSERT INTO "your table"
SELECT ... FROM "your table" WHERE key NOT IN (SELECT key FROM upsert);
```

r

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use a log rotation tool, eg: [`logrotate(8)`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) to regularly truncate or compress the log file when it reaches a certain size or age.

Comment: This is just a half solution. Log messages still get generated, CPU and IO is wasted.